# Updates, then crash

Tags: boot, crash

[image: Image of screen after failed boot]I use 18.04 LTS on a dual-boot Samsung ATIV Book 8. All was fine until this afternoon, when Software Updater informed me of new software updates awaiting. Didn't check which ones--hit OK. After, opened terminal and sudo apt upgrade. A couple upgrades happened.

Hit reboot. System reboots, get "ubuntu' screen, then a stream of messages. No boot.

Tried recovery mode. No luck. Tried reverting to earlier kernel. No luck.

NOT a "boot to black screen." See image attached.

Am I looking a complete partition reinstall in the face?

Comment: I too experience problems after the last update: screen resolution changed and no network access. 16.04lts here

Comment: Again, this is NOT, repeat NOT, a "boot to black screen" issue. See img above for error msgs.

Comment: "Black screen" doesn't mean "entirely black screen". The linked question also deals with *mostly* black or purple screens. The point is that no graphical session shows up. In your case this appears to be due to a (now fixed) bug in a package or some package management issue.

Comment: Thanks, David! I think it might be related to some interaction between a package and the GNOME desktop boot. Another update yesterday, and the desktop now take 3 minutes (and not, as before, 13 seconds) to load...

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have resolved the issue--largely by chance.

I discovered that once I arrived at the opening Plymouth bootscreen, if I hit <kbd>Return</kbd> & <kbd>Esc</kbd> 10 or 15 times the GNOME desktop could be cajoled to load after 60 or so seconds (not otherwise--I'd get the message dump in the image above and then the machine would cold power-off).

Once safely inside the desktop, I backed up /home and did another software update, then `sudo apt upgrade`. The following packages upgraded:

```
bluez
bluez-cups
blues-obexd
gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
gnome-desktop3-data
libbluetooth3
libgnome-desktop-3-17
python3-update-manager
update-manager
update-manager-core
```

All updates came from the `us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd repository`.

After that, boots have been normal. One of these packages (probably one or more of the `gnome desktop3` packages) seems to have been the problem.

Any ideas what might have happened? Hope this is useful, at any rate, to others who may have had this problem...